# Can't attach multiple Blob objects as attachments in MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating an google-app-script that converts documents and sends an email.

I have created two functions, one for converting a Google Doc to Microsoft Word and one for converting Google Sheets to Microsoft Excel. Both of these functions return a Blob object successfully.

I have been able to use the documented MailApp.sendEmail function to send an individual blob. But I keep running into an invalid argument error when I try to send two blobs in the same email.

My script is:

```
    //Convert Google Sheet page to Microsoft Excel Document, return BLOB
    function convert2Excel(docID) {

  var file          = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
  var url           = 
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+docID+"/export?forma‌t=xlsx";
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var fileName = file.getName() + '.xlsx';
  return [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];

};

//Convert Google Doc page to Microsoft Word Document, return BLOB for emailing
function convert2Word(docID){

  var file       = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
  var url        = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+docID+"/export?forma‌t=docx";
  var token      = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response   = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  var fileName = file.getName() + '.docx';
  return [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];

 };

//Send email with attachments
function sendEmail(att1,att2){
MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'The Subject', 'A Message', {attachments: [att1, att2]});
};

var att1=convert2Excel('sheetID string');
var att2=convert2Word('docID string');
sendEmail(att1,att2);
```

According to the documentation, this should work but I can't get multiple blob objects to work.

Comment: Can you post a link to the docs you are referencing?

Comment: I assume this isn't your full code?

Comment: Apologies, this is my first post and I'm new to scripting and this site.It's part of a larger set of scripts I'm using with a template Sheet. I was testing this by inserting the file Id's as strings. I didn't want to post the specific docs. If you paste a sheet doc ID string into convert2Excel(), replace email@mail.com with a valid email address and only pass att1 to the attachments it works. Same if you only pass att2. The conversions work, but the way I'm sending both of them to the attachments parameter does not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working with 2 attachments is that you are passing an array of arrays to the `attachments` argument of `.sendMail`()

There are 2 ways to get your code working. The line: `return [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];` By returning the blob inside the square bracket you are actually returning an array containing a blob. You can see this in the debugger:[image]

Remove the square brackets from the line `return [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];` to return the actual blob instead. In the debugger: [image]

Alternatively you could leave the square brackets and add `[0]` to `att1` and `att2` on the line `MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'The Subject', 'A Message', {attachments: [att1, att2]});
};` Like this : `MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'The Subject', 'A Message', {attachments: [att1[0], att2[0]]});
};`

Comment: Thanks, James. That works. I had thought that returning the arrays was correct but now I get it. Appreciate the time spent.