# Invalid argument: fileName error using MailApp.sendEmail()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting an error `Invalid argument: fileName(...)` using `MailApp.sendEmail(msg)`.

I have read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473743/cant-attach-multiple-blob-objects-as-attachments-in-mailapp-sendemail). According to the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473743/cant-attach-multiple-blob-objects-as-attachments-in-mailapp-sendemail), `MailApp.sendEmail({attachments: BlobSource[],...}` expects a blob source array. I have tried this with both the array and with a single blob source (i.e., without the `[]`) and get the same error.

```
function sendEmailNotifications(payroll){
  debug && Logger.log('sending email notifications')
  var emailTmpltId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('EMAIL_TEMPLATE')
  var messageTmplt = DocumentApp.openById(emailTmpltId).getBody().getText() // get the template text
  // Iterate through payroll and send emails.
  payroll.forEach(function(p){
    debug && Logger.log('starting email for '+p['EMPLOYEE_EMAIL'])
    var msg = {
      to: p['EMPLOYEE_EMAIL'],
      subject: p['PAY_DATE']+': Pay stub ['+p['EMPLOYEE_CODE']+']',
      body: emailMerge(messageTmplt, p),
      attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById(p['DOC_ID']).getBlob()], // per docs expects BlobSource[]

    }
    debug && Logger.log('sendEmailNotification: '+JSON.stringify(msg))
    MailApp.sendEmail(msg) // Invalid argument: fileName
  })
}
```

Note that the debug logs show correct data accept for `msg.attachments = {}` and the `DOC_ID` points to a valid PDF file.

Note also that the following test code using the `p['DOC_ID']` from the debug log returns a valid filename:

```
function testDocId() {
  var id = '1xh0HBWaANnFQ_AHbT6jc7pQWPbMQ9WXt'
  Logger.log('testDocId: document name: '+DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName())
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: set the name of the blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @|'-'| ..

That started me down the path... It turns out that I had an `'@'` character in the file name which works fine for `DriveApp.Files`; however, does not work for Blob names. When I removed the '@' the code worked correctly.